# Most efficient way to serve files through a PHP server from Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

I have a simple image processing server that handles authentication of images, resizing, cropping, etc.
If it recently did a relatively large operation such as resize an image, it will upload the new resized version back to Cloud Storage, which it will use next time that exact size is needed again.

My question is, next time someone requests that image, or the server is serving an unaltered image "directly" from the Google Cloud Storage bucket, what's the best method for my PHP server to "pass on" the data of the image to the user, using as little processing and memory as possible?

Right now my current working code boils down to:

```php
if ($image->exists()) {
    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
    echo $image->downloadAsString();
}
```

Which, just from looking at it, seems like  a bad way to do things. But I don't know so I'm asking.

Edit:
I am not looking for the most efficient way to serve images to the client in general or in any larger scheme, I am looking for the most efficient function(s) I can use already in PHP to accomplish what I'm trying to do with as little latency, CPU usage, and memory as possible.

"What I'm trying to do" being: In a running PHP script, verify that the user can access the image, check if the resized image exists, and if it does, relay it to the client. If it doesn't, resize the image, send it back to cloud storage for later retrieval, then send the resized image to the user. The only part I'm concerned about right now is how to pass the data from the bucket to the user.

Assume all servers including the bucket itself are in the same zone. I am not using a framework. I need to serve through the webserver, and for those that I don't need to, I use a load balancer to serve directly from the cloud storage. I am not using a CDN.

Comment: Edit your question with more details. 1) Are you using a framework such as Laravel? 2) Are the objects stored in Google Cloud Storage public? 3) Do you need to serve the files through your web server or can you use public access or signed URLs to service objects directly from Cloud Storage? 4) Are you using a CDN? 5) Based upon the information in your question, **most efficient** is hard to determine. In general, the most efficient way, considering cost and latency, is to serve the objects directly from Cloud Storage to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`downloadAsStream()`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-storage/blob/22dd587e5136248e31c8ce047c331acbe74ffbb7/src/StorageObject.php#L626-L681) and [`stream_copy_to_stream()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-copy-to-stream) should give you the best results. Eg:

```php
if ($image->exists()) {
    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
    stream_copy_to_stream($image->downloadAsStream(), STDOUT);
}
```

In this case PHP should copy file data directly to output as it is retrieved with maximal efficiency, memory or otherwise.

If you scroll up a bit in the source [`downloadAsString()`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-storage/blob/22dd587e5136248e31c8ce047c331acbe74ffbb7/src/StorageObject.php#L578-L581) just calls the stream and returns the whole thing as a string, which will cram all that file data into memory.

Also, for best results, grab the StorageObject metadata and set a `Content-Length:` header. This generally makes HTTP clients behave a bit better. I believe this will be in what's returned by `$image->info()`.

Comment: This answer does not factor in network pricing, latency, object caching, or the issues of how to deliver objects from Google Cloud Storage. This answer just considers optimizing data transfers in memory. Serving objects from a VM webserver is more expensive than serving objects from Cloud Storage.

Comment: @JohnHanley by all means, write your own answer and rejoice that accepted answers aren't pinned to the top anymore.

Comment: I asked the OP for more detail so that a good answer can be created. Your answer is not wrong but more details should be considered IMHO.